# Docker error response from daemon no such file or directory while docker load

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I have created a tar file from docker image and try to load into another system docker.

Code i used for create ubuntu.tar file is **docker save**

then i copy that tar file into another system ubuntu system's home path.

then try to load it into docker using command **docker load < ubuntu.tar**

but it shows "error response from daemon no such file or directory "  error.

what is the issue. Please help

Comment: Please check if `ubuntu.tar` is empty. I had this problem. Try creating or downloading the `ubuntu.tar` again.